# Triggering an event after a "Like"

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom-events, facebook-like

In the case that I would like to embed the like button on a lightbox that displays over my website, is there a way to trigger an event that leads to either:

1. a second lightbox that thanks the visitor after they click "like"
2. a new tab that thanks the visitor after they click "like"

The goal is to keep the UX as optimal as possible throughout this process. I figured this has to be possible, but I cannot find any resources that explain the best practices when executing it.

Also, I'd like to be able to do the same thing with the Send button, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/, something like:

```
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        greetUser();
    }
  );
```

should work.